# django-ckeditor codesnippet is not responsive

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I am using the Django-CKEditor and the problem that I have is that the code area (`codesnippet` plugin)  is not responsive and some of the code gets out of the highlighted area as I make the page smaller. Also, I am using bootstrap in my project.

It's okay on larger screens:

[image]

**But** as I make the size smaller The problem happens:

[image]

I have done the following configuration in my `settings.py` and on the `HTML page`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
# other apps

    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]
```

```
# ckeditor

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "ckeditor_uploads/"

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
        # 'height': 300,
        # 'width': 960,
        'width': 'auto',
        'height': '600',

         

        'extraPlugins': ','.join([
            
            'codesnippet',

            'div',
            'autolink',
            'autoembed',
            'embedsemantic',
            'autogrow',
          
            'widget',
            'lineutils',
            'clipboard',
            'dialog',
            'dialogui',
            'elementspath',

            'mathjax',
        ]),
    },
}
```

```
{% load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static  'ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/codesnippet/lib/highlight/styles/default.css' %}"/>
<script src="{% static 'ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/codesnippet/lib/highlight/highlight.pack.js' %}"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

And also I have collected the static files:

[image]

Thank you for anything you can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this kind of issue requires the `overflow` property to be set. In this case, the following solves the problem.

```css
    pre code.hljs {
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

Just pop it into your CSS file.